# Discord.pyを使っていたのですが、ボットに下記のコードを使ってembedを表示させようとしても表示されません。どこを修正すればいいのでしょうか？

Tags: python, discord

Discord.pyを使っていたのですが、ボットに下記のコードを使ってembedを表示させようとしても表示されません。どこを修正すればいいのでしょうか？

````
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$test'):
        await message.channel.send((embed))
embed=embedobj
embed = discord.Embed(title="ぼっとヘルプ一覧", colour=discord.Colour(0x112f43), url="https://discordapp.com", description="```Prefix:$```", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1551172370))

embed.set_image()
embed.set_thumbnail(url="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-k74QBLjNuyg/TtiCcfDf2pI/AAAAAAAAAGw/coMwMiItguo/s1600/Mameshiba-Edamame-Wallpaper.jpg")
embed.set_author(name="eDaMAme#1597", url="https://discordapp.com", icon_url="https://bit.ly/2SsIBiC")
embed.set_footer(text="footer text", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png")

embed.add_field(name="$hello", value="挨拶をします")
embed.add_field(name="$weather", value="お天気情報")
embed.add_field(name="$zisin", value="地震情報")
embed.add_field(name="$happy,$sad,$angry", value="絵文字表示", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="そのほかいろいろ", value="追加予定", inline=True)

await bot.say(embed=embed)

client.run('token')
````

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/176583

Comment: @wiiuuxx さん、Python のバージョンと、`pip show discord.py` で表示されるはずの discord.py のバージョンを質問文に含めてくださいませんか？　環境情報が無いと回答者が問題を再現しにくくなります。

Comment: @wiiuuxx さん、マルチポストについて、スタック・オーバーフロー側の意見はこちらをご一読ください：[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)

Answer (score 1):

asyncバージョンですね。もうそろそろ巨大アップデートがあるので、早めに新バージョンの[Rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/index.html)に乗り換えたほうがいいですよ。

本題に入りますが、まず`embed=embedobj`が気になります。embedobjは未定義のようです。この行は要らないと思います。
また、`embed.set_image()`には引数がいります。画像を付けない場合はその行はなくてOKです。

Comment: 補足記事 [discord.pyのasync/rewriteとは何なのか](https://qiita.com/1ntegrale9/items/f4c47a6a69ecf23fc5db)、[discord.py v1.0.0a(rewrite) を pipenv で利用する](https://qiita.com/1ntegrale9/items/7917ff81165e0161b4af)

Answer (score 0):

エラーは出てないですよね？

```
if message.author == client.user:
```

これが問題ではないでしょうか？

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

これではユーザーが発したメッセージをはじくということになります。
BOTの発言をはじきたかったら

```
if message.author.bot:
    return
```

このように書き換えましょう。

Comment: 前半部分は正しく bot の発言を弾いていそうです。[`client.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/api.html#discord.Client.user) はこの場合 bot 自身を表します。

Answer (score 0):

````py
import discord

embed = discord.Embed(title="ぼっとヘルプ一覧", colour=discord.Colour(0x112f43), url="https://discordapp.com", description="```Prefix:$```", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1551172370))
embed.set_thumbnail(url="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-k74QBLjNuyg/TtiCcfDf2pI/AAAAAAAAAGw/coMwMiItguo/s1600/Mameshiba-Edamame-Wallpaper.jpg")
embed.set_author(name="eDaMAme#1597", url="https://discordapp.com", icon_url="https://bit.ly/2SsIBiC")
embed.set_footer(text="footer text", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png")
embed.add_field(name="$hello", value="挨拶をします")
embed.add_field(name="$weather", value="お天気情報")
embed.add_field(name="$zisin", value="地震情報")
embed.add_field(name="$happy,$sad,$angry", value="絵文字表示", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="そのほかいろいろ", value="追加予定", inline=True)

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$test'):
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run('token')
````